# windows authentication with a custom login page

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, authentication, windows-authentication

So i only need to do windows authentication and not forms authentication.

Instead of giving the user a popup box for login.. i want to have a login page with Username, domain and password..also an option of remember password.
If the user does not exist it should just show that wrong username and password.

I have 2 types of users: administrators & users.

If its an administrator it should go to admin.aspx and if its User, it should go to users.aspx.

any help is appreciated. I have tried to do this but i actually mixed forms and windows authentication, and i think i have security issues.

Answer (score 1):

Use the ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650307.aspx

Comment: i considered using active directory method... but i have a doubt in it:
what if my user is a local user.. will it be in the active directory?

Comment: well, i don't think there is a provider OOTB to do this but here is a question that seems to have the answer to local user authentication.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/609553/authentication-of-windows-local-user-account-in-c-3-0